# How files in the etc directory should be accessed?

Tags: config

When invoking `C-h h`, emacs opens a `HELLO` file located in `Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc` directory (under Mac OS X). I looked for myself and there are tons of interesting files (`JOKES`, `PROBLEMS`, etc.) but I'm not certain what's the canonical way of accessing those files.

(Not too sure what tag should apply here.)